# why is openDatabase undefined on WP8.1/WP10 with PGB?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, web-sql

We are using Adobe Phonegap Build for a CLI 5.1.1 project.

We want to reference this [async web sql plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-websql-async) in config.xml file as follows;

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-websql-async" source="npm"></plugin>
```

There are no build errors. However the app fails on Windows Phone because `openDatabase` is not defined.

Is this because the [base plugin](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql) is for cordova CLI 3.x or is there any way to get async sql openDatabase working with 5.1.1 ?

The background for asking - native IndexedDB runs fine on WP8.x but storage  seems limited to some low quota amount with WP10. Hence looking for another implementation and the aysnc web plugin looks like an option as we already use Lawnchair.

Comment: post build the PGB plugins tab shows cordova-plugin-websql-async listed with version *

Comment: you need to ask the author of the plugin. [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-websql-async) listing - [github repository](https://github.com/Thinkwise/cordova-plugin-websql)